# I am getting Cross-Site Scripting: Poor Validation on Struts call to a bean class

Tags: jsp, struts2, xss, fortify, esapi

I scanned my application in HP Fortify and getting an issue `Cross-Site Scripting: Poor Validation`. I am using ESAPI library.  I am getting this finding on a Struts application.

```jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<form method='post' name='<s:property value='tableBean.formName'/>' action='Notification.action'>
```

```java
public String printApplications() throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setAttribute(TableDisplayBean.TABLE_BEAN, tableBean);
}
```

What would be the proper syntax to use ESAPI to encode `tableBean.formName`?

Comment: Why do you set dynamic `name` in the form?

Comment: I did not code the original implementation.  This is inherited legacy code.  My job is to remediate the Fortify findings without changing the overall implementation.

Comment: Question:  Is "formName" user-controllable at all?  If it isn't, then this and even the esapi version I recommended is moot point and this can be marked as a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

Before:

```
<html lang="${myVar}">
```

The appropriate syntax would look like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/esapi.tld" prefix="esapi" %>
<html lang="<esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>${myvar}</esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>">
```

In your case, use `HTMLAttribute` because the value you're getting dynamically is being inserted into the "name" attribute on the tag.  If it was going to be say, in a p-tag, you'd use `esapi:encodeForHTML`.

```
<p>
<esapi:encodeForHTML>${myVal}</esapi:encodeForHTML>
</p>
```

Also, if the value would be received by a javascript function on rendering, `esapi:encodeForJavaScript`.

Encoding always has a proper context, and the context is answered by the question, "What kind of interpreter will first receive this data?"

=============================================

I wasn't explicit enough.  The example I provided will only escape for HTML attributes when it sounds like it's being deposited as raw HTML. The general example above has been reworked.

Using your example, try:

```
<form method='post' name='<s:property value=<esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>'tableBean.formName'<esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>/>' action='Notification.action'>
```

I'm used to JSTL syntax, so I'm not 100% sure the best way to wrap your variable here.  You'll have to play with it.  Alternatively, you could add a method to `tableBean` like `tableBean.attributeEscapedFormName` which would look like:

```
public class TableBean{
    String formName;
    public String htmlAttributeEscapedFormName(){
        return ESAPI.encoder().escapeForHTMLAttribute( formName );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach and now Fortify flags it as a "Critical XSS Scripting Reflected" rather than a "Medium XSS Scripting Poor Validation"

Comment: @RichardSandoz that's because my original example was incomplete.  But if the issue is still there, I would try my second suggestion and handle escaping at the bean level.  My apologies for not knowing struts view syntax better!

Answer (score 0):

You should read [`property` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/property-tag.html)  reference to better understand how to use it.

> Used to get the property of a value, which will default to the top of
> the stack if none is specified. Parameters
>
> Dynamic Attributes Allowed: `false`
>
> The default
> value to be used if value attribute is `null`
>
> - `escapeCsv` false   false   false   Boolean Whether to escape CSV (useful to escape a value for a column)
> - `escapeHtml`    false   true    false   Boolean Whether to escape HTML
> - `escapeJavaScript`  false   false   false   Boolean Whether to escape Javascript
> - `escapeXml` false   false   false   Boolean Whether to escape XML
> - `value` false     false   Object  Value to be displayed
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>  <s:push value="myBean">
>
>  <!-- Example 1: -->
>  <s:property value="myBeanProperty" />
>
>  <!-- Example 2: -->TextUtils
>  <s:property value="myBeanProperty" default="a default value" /> 
> </s:push>
> ```
>
> Example 1 prints the result of `myBean`'s `getMyBeanProperty()`
> method.
> Example 2 prints the result of `myBean`'s `getMyBeanProperty()`
> method and if it is `null`, print 'a default value' instead.

Comment: I did not code the original implementation.  This pattern actually occurs in hundreds of places throughout our legacy codebase.  It is actually working.  My job is to replace occurrences of '<s:property value="tableBean.formName"/>' with something such as '<esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>${tableBean.formName}</esapi:encodeForHTMLAttribute>' that will pass Fortify muster.  In this example, the problem is not fixed but actually goes from Medium to Critical, so I cannot use this.

Comment: And, yes, I did experiment with the various escape attributes on the struts taglib and was unable to resolve my main issue which was to remediate the Fortify findings.  I even found a guide on nutshellsoftware.org that goes as far as customizing parts of struts, which we cannot do to 3rd party libs due to upgrade support, etc.

Comment: @RichardSandoz yes, upgrades requires support, however struts team didn't produce much deprecated stuff which needs to rewrite. Usually the application after upgrade stops working and you have to dig the docs and source code if nobody answers the cause of the problem. Some 3rd party tools might produce incorrect results due to lack of knowledge of the framework features or another software involved that misplace results. If you want to check how Struts escapes content with maximum safety I recommend you to use all attributes.