# How to create xss included project onStruts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, xss

I want to create test-case for xss in Struts2 for my Web App Vuln. Scanner.
I'm already done one project but its encoding the characters like `< >`

I thought it would trigger xss, but that's the result.

**[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l4Zm.png)**

Comment: It's unclear to me what kind of help or information you're requesting. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. "It's encoding..." What is? The default S2 tags? Yeah, they do that, to avoid at least one class of XSS attacks. Please provide actual details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977126/573032